# Automatic voice recognition when a word is said

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, voice-recognition

I am trying to create a simulation of Alexa or Google Home (very basic). I am using the SpeechRecognition module with the Google as recognizer. I have managed to get it working but I don't know how to run the whole script when I say a word (I want it to be hearing always (as Alexa does)).

Ex:
'Hey, Robot'
AI = Hi, how may I help you? (runs whole script)

I had thought about looping through a piece of code every 5 seconds and then connecting to Google API but this isn't possible as the API is limited to 50 requests per day.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "Silence" threshold to identify need of sending request to google, with that approach you will avoid sending to match requests. For code sample see [Python record audio on detected sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406570/python-record-audio-on-detected-sound).

Alternatively you can use open sourced speech recognition packages and end up with independent application, see [The Ultimate Guide To Speech Recognition With Python](https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/) article for that approach.

However, if you still prefer using of the remote API, you can combine approaches above, and use [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) to understand the `Hey, Robot` phrase and after that, switch application to use Google API for speech recognition for some small short period of time, of course the threshold check shall be used to avoid querying Google API when client don't continue to speak after saying `Hey, Robot`.

Good Luck !

Answer (score 2):

Go with CMU Sphinx. It does exactly what you want. See here:
https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/