# Ignore background noise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, voice-recognition, pyaudio

I am making a voice recognition software for my computer but I have some problems:
1) Is there a way to ignore background noise? I want the program to end when there is x amount of time without noise but background noise could keep it awake indefinitely.
2) same thing but reverse, I want it to start when it hears a voice but loud enough background noise will start it as well.

Comment: For your 2nd problem I searched "pyaudio threshold" and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668442/detect-and-record-a-sound-with-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I can't provide any code, only pseudocode. You can create en enum, or a list, of possible phonemes spoken. Activate the program only when the ADSR pattern of the phoneme is recognized, with volume as a secondary indicator, to separate "background" phonemes. If the background noise is so loud that it interferes with the recognition of the phoneme, then it shouldn't be considered a background sound in the first place.

```
Aah = 1
Ahh = 2
Ehh = 3 
...
if soundEvent == true:

    if phoneme.type = Aah:
    what_i_said = "a"
...
```

Comment: You don't need to write down what they said, but as long as a phoneme is spoken, you know someone is talking.

Comment: Who ever voted this down had better have a better answer for me

Comment: I know, probably rogue or accidental voting, did you vote up to neutralize it?