# Audio Recording in Python

Tags: python, audio-recording, microphone, alsa, pyaudio

I want to record short audio clips from a USB microphone in Python. I have tried pyaudio, which seemed to fail communicating with ALSA, and alsaaudio, the code example of which produces an unreadable files.

So my question: What is the easiest way to record clips from a USB mic in Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect & Record Audio in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892199/detect-record-audio-in-python)

Comment: I have used PyGStreamer for it and it worked well but I cannot really say that it is the solution to your question.

Comment: On Windows, alsaaudio did not appear to be a viable option because the default pip install wanted vsstudio so it could compile from source.  The [Detect & Record Audio in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892199/detect-record-audio-in-python) mentioned earlier lead me to pyaudio, which worked well for me. Again, this is all on Windows, but I think the OP here is talking about Linux.

Answer (score 13):

This script records to test.wav while printing the current amplitute:

```
import alsaaudio, wave, numpy

inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE)
inp.setchannels(1)
inp.setrate(44100)
inp.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
inp.setperiodsize(1024)

w = wave.open('test.wav', 'w')
w.setnchannels(1)
w.setsampwidth(2)
w.setframerate(44100)

while True:
    l, data = inp.read()
    a = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype='int16')
    print numpy.abs(a).mean()
    w.writeframes(data)
```

Comment: coulnd't you use `array.array('h', data)` or `struct` instead of numpy?

Comment: I mainly get audio into Python to do signal processing. For that you want numpy. For simple recording I would just use a command line tool like 'arecord'.  In Python I can do FFT and check if a certain frequency is dominant with just three lines of code or so.

Comment: Someone verify this and comment whether it works.. it's been ages since I asked this and I should really accept something.