# Direct output audio to input mic using on linux with python

Tags: python, alsa

Hi I have a piece of code for recording audio using python and alsa audio module 
based on the example described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867675/audio-recording-in-python) to test out some pitch detection algorithms. I was hoping if there's a way I could somehow record the audio from  browser or media player into my program.

Here's my code :-

```
import alsaaudio
import struct
from aubio.task import *

# Constants 
CHANNELS = 1
INFORMAT = alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_FLOAT_LE
RATE = 44100
FRAMESIZE = 1024
PITCHALG = aubio_pitch_yin
PITCHOUT = aubio_pitchm_freq


# set up the audio input
recorder = alsaaudio.PCM(type = alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE)
recorder.setchannels(CHANNELS)
recorder.setrate(RATE)
recorder.setformat(INFORMAT) 
recorder.setperiodsize(FRAMESIZE)

# set up pitch detect
detect = new_aubio_pitchdetection(FRAMESIZE, FRAMESIZE / 2, CHANNELS,
                              RATE, PITCHALG, PITCHOUT)
buf = new_fvec(FRAMESIZE, CHANNELS)

def pitches():
    runflag = 1
    while runflag :

        # read data from audio input
        [length, data] = recorder.read()

        # convert to an array of floats
        floats = struct.unpack('f' * FRAMESIZE,data)

        # copy floats into structure
        for i in range(len(floats)):
            fvec_write_sample(buf, floats[i], 0, i)

        # find pitch of audio frame
        freq = aubio_pitchdetection(detect, buf)
```

Right now I am using a cable to direct audio out to input but the quality as expected is not very good.

Comment: does it need to be programmatically

Comment: For future reference, you should still paste code examples in, rather than linking to them.

Comment: The answers here _may_ be helpful: [Capture audio out Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888058/capture-audio-out-python)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes I want to read the data into an array

Comment: @jdborg Thanks it's all there now