# How to save sound produced from text as mp3 or wave in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to convert text to sound file and save to system.
i tried pyttsx and read [this](http://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/v1.1/engine.html#the-engine-factory) doc. but no option to save the produced sound.
Then i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900137/recording-synthesized-text-to-speech-to-a-file-in-python) answer and installed espeak. i tried this

```
import subprocess

def textToWav(text,file_name):
   subprocess.call(["espeak",text,"-w"+file_name+".wav"])

textToWav('hello world','hello')
```

code. but it producing error something like
**not able to find subprocess espeak**.
But i can run GUI application of espeak now.
What is the problem?

Comment: Can you type "espeak 'some text' -wfilename.wav" into a shell and have it create the sound file?

Comment: yes if cmd directory in  C://pgr_dir/espeak/commandline/

Comment: Try providing the full path for the espeak command:  `subprocess.call(["C:\\\\pgr_dir\\espeak\\commandline\\espeak",text,"-w"+file_name+".wav"])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when issuing a subprocess.call you are doing exactly the same as typing the commands in in the directory that your python code would run.  You need to be able to cope with things like:

- The other program is not installed
- It is not on the path
- It has not been installed to the standard location

  etc.