# Save the output of SAPI voice to a file in python

Tags: python, text-to-speech, espeak, ivona

I'm using python to execute a subprocess like so:

`subprocess.call(["espeak", "-v Ivona 2 Joey -w "+file_name+".wav", text])`

I'm not sure how to use the Ivona 2 Joey voice. When I run the `TTSApp.exe` file, I can see it in the drop down under "Voice".

and I have read through this http://espeak.sourceforge.net/voices.html.

and when I do `espeak --voices`, I don't see `Ivona` in there.

Or is there another way to do it? I have tried `pyttsx` but it has no output to wav.

All I'm trying to do is use a voice synthesizer to read text using Ivona voice and output to a wav file.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900137/recording-synthesized-text-to-speech-to-a-file-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646949/how-to-save-sound-produced-from-text-as-mp3-or-wave-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014468/how-to-save-the-output-of-pyttsx-to-wav-file

Answer (score 0):

Joey is voice of Ivona TTS, a commercial product. The voice is available through SAPI interface. You can not access this voice through espeak, espeak only supports espeak voices.

You can use more advanced SAPI wrapper to save output to the wav file. For example you can try

https://github.com/DeepHorizons/tts

The code should look like this:

```
import tts.sapi
voice = tts.sapi.Sapi()
voice.set_voice("Joey")
voice.create_recording('hello.wav', "Hello")
```

Comment: I'm having problems running code in python 2.7.13, i'm getting a `TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)` error.

Comment: You can remove the line `super().__init__()` from the sapi.py.

Comment: I deleted the line. now getting this `File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tts\sapi.py", line 97, in _create_stream
    stream.Open(filename, SpeechLib.SSFMCreateForWrite)
COMError: (-2147287038, None, (None, None, None, 0, None))`