# Espeak on windows 7 and python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-to-speech, espeak

On the begin I'll say that there is a similar post here: [How to use espeak with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547531/how-to-use-espeak-with-python) and I was using answers from this post, but still i'm getting errors, so maybe u'll be able to help me fix it.

```
import subprocess
text = '"Hello world"'
subprocess.call('espeak '+text, shell=True)
```

This code gives me an error:

```
'espeak' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

ps. I think I installed espeak correctly, because I can use in CMD line:

```
espeak "text"
```

and it will say "text" correctly.

PS2. probably answer for this question will be the answer for my another question I posted earlier. ([How to save the output of PyTTSx to wav file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014468/how-to-save-the-output-of-pyttsx-to-wav-file))

Comment: Are you sure you can run `espeak` from the command line, in the same terminal you call your python script?

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I'm using espeak "say" on my CMD console in windows (start->cmd) and there works correctly. But when I use python terminal in my pyCharm it gives me an 'espeak' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file error. Any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: Try adding the full path to your `espeak` installation

Comment: worked out, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ping', '127.0.0.1'], shell=True)
```

Comment: with just:
`import subprocess
text = "something"
subprocess.call(['espeak', text], shell=True)`

it still gives me an 'espeak' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. like I writed on the begin of my post

Comment: try 'c:\\espeak.bat'

Comment: dont know what you mean. u want me to put this in console or what?

Comment: Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

it seems ping work normally.

Comment: subprocess.call(['c:\\123\\espeak.exe', text], shell=True)

Comment: Ok, it worked out, it readed what I wanted, I'm glad you helped me out and really thanks for help, but I'm now curious why my start->cmd doesn't work like python terminal... where is the difference? Maybe u know where I can find article which will explain me this, or maybe u can answer in few words? :-)

Comment: ahh, Its problem with paths. I used os.chdir(os.path.join("C:\Program Files (x86)\eSpeak\command_line")) and it work now like it should :-)