# Acquiring audio data from Firewire using python

Tags: python, firewire

I have an M-Audio Profire 2626 multichannel sound acquisition hardware, which I want to control using my laptop. The m-Audio device comes with a Firewire interface. I would want to know if I can control this device using Python through Firewire interface

Comment: Does this help? [Detect & Record Audio in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/892199/222914)

Comment: It would be worth mentioning what platform you are working on.  And by control do you mean recording and playback, or do you mean controlling monitoring, routing, and pre-amps.