# Record audio in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pyaudio

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892199/detect-record-audio-in-python) provides some useful code for recording an audio file in a Python program.

However, this does not seem to work in a Jupyter Notebook. It would seem that in this case the audio input of the server machine is used and not the audio input of the web browser.

Is there a way to record audio in a Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with IPyWebRTC: https://ipywebrtc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

You could use the [Camera Stream](https://ipywebrtc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CameraStream.html) to attach to the browsers webcam capabilities and record audio from there.