# Remotely recording audio in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, audio, jupyter, recording

Is there a way to record audio on a remote jupyter notebook using local microphone?

I'm trying to record audio on a remote jupyter notebook using my local machine's microphone. However, when I follow instructions in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892199/detect-record-audio-in-python/)! , the remote machine's microphone is used instead. We've developed a workaround by creating a Flask webserver on our remote machine, but I'm curious as to how we can use jupyter directly.