# How can I record microphone audio to a file with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wav, pocketsphinx

What I would like to do is start recording audio to a file (microphone.wav) and then continue recording audio until there is no dialogue detected from the microphone for two seconds. At which point it will finish and save so I can process the file with pocketsphinx. Is this possible?

Comment: You should check this old question: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892199/detect-record-audio-in-python), you could use pyaudio

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I'm looking for. I don't want it to cut silence out I want it to keep recording until it is silent for a specified time. Also I don't want to result as an array but just as a file.