# adintool or psychopy for capturing speech for recognition by Julius?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, psychopy, julius-speech

I am working with [Julius](https://github.com/julius-speech/julius) to recognize speech. I would like to have speech passed to Julius consistently as long as the mic is running, and store individual words to a library. I am looking for the best method to record and/or pass audio only when there is speech detected with the lowest use of memory and data.

[adintool](https://julius.osdn.jp/juliusbook/en/adintool.html) is developed for Julius. Would code like this:

```
(sender) % adintool -in mic -out adinnet -server receiver_hostname
(receiver) % julius -C ... -input adinnet
```

suggest that using adintool would allow me to pass the audio to Julius in server mode?

[PsychoPy](https://www.psychopy.org/api/microphone.html) is Python based, and while I'm more familiar with Python Julius is written in C. PsychoPy would record sound and send it to Julius as a WAV file. This makes me suspect that it will lean heavier on memory and data resources.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892199/detect-record-audio-in-python) has some useful suggestions for recording only when there is a sound. Would it make sense to use this before either adintool or PsychoPy? Or do those tools already have this capability?

SUMMARY: Between adintool and PsychoPy, which is the best for lightweight audio capture for processing by julius, and would additional code be required to record/capture only when there is sound?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use something like https://pythonhosted.org/pyjulius/ from Python. Julius server will record audio by itself and just send you back the transcribed text.

Comment: Thank you! I'll test this out.