# Detect & Record Audio to PCM format in Python

Tags: python, wav, audio-recording, pcm

I need to record audio in PCM file format from raspberry pi whenever it detects a sound (passing certain threshold), and stops when it goes silent. As such, I came across a previously asked question and followed the top answer in [Detect & Record Audio in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892199/detect-record-audio-in-python/892293). However, it saves the file in WAV format, but the API that I am using only reads format of pcm, speex or speex-wb.

How can I go about recording the audio in pcm format while keeping the function of recording only when it detects a sound?

```
from sys import byteorder
from array import array
from struct import pack

import pyaudio
import wave

THRESHOLD = 8000
chans = 1
chunk = 4096
form_1 = pyaudio.paInt16
samp_rate = 44100
dev_index = 2 # device index found by p.get_device_info_by_index(ii)
wav_output_filename = 'test4.wav'

def is_silent(snd_data):
    "Returns 'True' if below the 'silent' threshold"
    return max(snd_data) < THRESHOLD

def normalize(snd_data):
    "Average the volume out"
    MAXIMUM = 16384
    times = float(MAXIMUM)/max(abs(i) for i in snd_data)

    r = array('h')
    for i in snd_data:
        r.append(int(i*times))
    return r

def trim(snd_data):
    "Trim the blank spots at the start and end"
    def _trim(snd_data):
        snd_started = False
        r = array('h')

        for i in snd_data:
            if not snd_started and abs(i)>THRESHOLD:
                snd_started = True
                r.append(i)

            elif snd_started:
                r.append(i)
        return r

    # Trim to the left
    snd_data = _trim(snd_data)

    # Trim to the right
    snd_data.reverse()
    snd_data = _trim(snd_data)
    snd_data.reverse()
    return snd_data

def add_silence(snd_data, seconds):
    "Add silence to the start and end of 'snd_data' of length 'seconds' (float)"
    silence = [0] * int(seconds * samp_rate)
    r = array('h', silence)
    r.extend(snd_data)
    r.extend(silence)
    return r

def record():
    """
    Record a word or words from the microphone and 
    return the data as an array of signed shorts.

    Normalizes the audio, trims silence from the 
    start and end, and pads with 0.5 seconds of 
    blank sound to make sure VLC et al can play 
    it without getting chopped off.
    """
    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = audio.open(format = form_1, channels=chans, rate = samp_rate,
                    input_device_index = dev_index, input = True, #output=True,
                    frames_per_buffer = chunk)

    num_silent = 0
    snd_started = False

    r = array('h')

    while 1:
        # little endian, signed short
        snd_data = array('h', stream.read(chunk, exception_on_overflow = False))
        if byteorder == 'big':
            snd_data.byteswap()
        r.extend(snd_data)

        silent = is_silent(snd_data)

        if silent and snd_started:
            num_silent += 1
        elif not silent and not snd_started:
            snd_started = True

        if snd_started and num_silent > 30:
            break

    sample_width = audio.get_sample_size(form_1)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    audio.terminate()

    r = normalize(r)
    r = trim(r)
    r = add_silence(r, 0.5)
    return sample_width, r

def record_to_file(path):
    "Records from the microphone and outputs the resulting data to 'path'"
    sample_width, data = record()
    data = pack('<' + ('h'*len(data)), *data)

    wf = wave.open(path, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(chans)
    wf.setsampwidth(sample_width) #
    wf.setframerate(samp_rate)
    wf.writeframes(data) #
    wf.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("please speak a word into the microphone")
    record_to_file(wav_output_filename)
    print("done - result written to " + wav_output_filename)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am unable to find any solutions in formating the audio file into pcm, but I found that I was able to process the audio in wav format in sampling rate 16k. So I will leave it with that.