# Sound activated recording and advanced filtering on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, audio, raspbian

I'm making a Raspberry Pi bat detector using a [USB-powered ultrasonic microphone](https://batsound.com/product/m500-384-usb-ultrasound-microphone/). I want to be able to record bats while excluding insects and other non-bat noises. Recording needs to be sound-triggered to avoid filling the SD card too quickly and to aid with analysis. [This website](http://pibat.afraidofsunlight.co.uk/sound-activated-recording) explains how to do this with SoX:

```
rec - c1 -r 192000 record.wav sinc 10k silence 1 0.1 1% trim 0 5
```

This records for 5 seconds after a trigger sound of at least 0.1 seconds and includes a 10kHz high pass filter. This is a good start, but what I'd really like is an advanced filter that excludes crickets and other non-bat noises. Insect and bat calls overlap in frequency so a high pass or band filter won't do.

The [Elekon Batlogger](https://www.batlogger.com/en/) does this with a period trigger that analyses zero crossings. From the Batlogger website:

> The difference in sound production of bats (vocal cords) and insects
> (stridulation) affects the period continuity. The period trigger takes
> advantage of this:
> [image]
>
> The trigger fires when ProdVal and DivVal are lower than the set
> limits, so if the values ​​are within the yellow range.
> (Values mean default values): ProdVal = 8, higher values ​​trigger
> easier DivVal = 20, higher values ​​trigger easier

Translated text from the image:

> Bat: Tonal signal
>
> Period constant => zero crossings / time = stable
>
> Insects: scratching
>
> Period constant => zero crossings / time = differs
>
> MN => mean value of the number of periods per measurement interval
>
> SD => standard deviation of the number of periods
>
> Higher values trigger better even at low frequencies (also insects!)
> And vice versa

Is there a way to implement this (or something to the same effect) in Raspberry Pi OS? The language I'm most familiar with is R. Based on answers to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28059/is-r-suitable-for-digital-signal-processing) it seems like R would be suitable for this problem, although if R isn't the best choice then I'm open to other suggestions.

I'd really appreciate some working code for recording audio and filtering as described above. My desired output is 5 second files that contain bat calls, not insects or noise. Needs to be efficient in terms of CPU / power use and needs to work on-the-fly.

Example recordings of bats and insects [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/41wml9iycw1w9yi/example%20files.zip?dl=0).

---

## UPDATE:

I've got a basic sound-activated script working in Python ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43304429/1640528)) but I'm not sure how to include an advanced filter in this:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
from array import array
 import time
 
FORMAT=pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS=1
RATE=44100
CHUNK=1024
RECORD_SECONDS=5

audio=pyaudio.PyAudio() 

stream=audio.open(format=FORMAT,channels=CHANNELS, 
                  rate=RATE,
                  input=True,
                  frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

nighttime=True # I will expand this later

while nighttime:
     data=stream.read(CHUNK)
     data_chunk=array('h',data)
     vol=max(data_chunk)
     if(vol>=3000):
         print("recording triggered")
         frames=[]
         for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
             data = stream.read(CHUNK)
             frames.append(data)
         print("recording saved")
         # write to file
         words = ["RECORDING-", time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"), ".wav"]
         FILE_NAME= "".join(words) 
         wavfile=wave.open(FILE_NAME,'wb')
         wavfile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
         wavfile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
         wavfile.setframerate(RATE)
         wavfile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
         wavfile.close()
     # check if still nighttime
     nighttime=True # I will expand this later
 
 stream.stop_stream()
 stream.close()
 audio.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

R should be capable of doing this in post-processing. If you want this done on a live audio recording/stream, I'd suggest you look for a different tool.

## Longer Answer

R is capable of processing audio files through several packages (most notable seem to be [tuneR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tuneR/index.html)), but I'm fairly sure that will be limited to post-collection processing, i.e. analysing the files you have already collected, rather than a 'live' filtering of streaming audio input.

There are a couple of approaches you could take to 'live' filtering of the insect/unwanted sounds. One would be to just record files like you have listed above, and then write R code to process them (you could automate this on a schedule with cron for example) and discard parts or files that don't match your criteria. If you are concerned about SD card space you can also offload these files to another location after processing (i.e. upload to another drive somewhere). You could make this a fairly short time frame (at the risk of CPU usage on the Pi), to get an 'almost-live' processing approach.

Another approach would be to look more at the [sox documentation](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) and see if there are options in there to achieve what you want based on streaming audio input, or see if there is another tool that you can stream input to, that will allow that sort of filtering.

Viel Glück!

Comment: Thanks @SamRogers for your answer. I have considered this as an option (recording everything and then later filtering with R) but this seems like a really inefficient approach. I've looked through the sox documentation and have been looking for other tools but haven't been able to find a solution. Which is why I asked the question here. Do you know of another tool or have any code that might help me?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really know of any other tools I'm sorry :(

Comment: Perhaps you could ask on "Software Recommendations Stack Exchange" https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com?