# Detect and split on silence while it is recording in Python

Tags: python, audio-recording

I need to record the audio and while it is still being recorded I need to detect the silences and split it into separate files. Is there a way to do so while the audio is still being recorded and terminate the recording when the silence has been for like 3 sec maybe. I found an answer really useful.I found an answer really useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16385946/12027530
How can I do this while it is still being recorded?